# Java regex - remove quotes unless preceded by odd number of backslashes

Tags: java, regex

I am using regex to strip quotes from a String value. These String values can contain escaped quotes but also escaped backslash characters.

I do not want to remove escaped quotes, only non-escaped quotes. However, the cases where escaped backslash characters are preceding a non-escaped quote is causing difficulty.

I want results like the following:

```
"value"         ->  value
'value'         ->  value
"\"value\""     ->  \"value\"   <-- contains escaped quotes
"value\"        ->  value\"
"value\\"       ->  value\\     <-- contains escaped backslash before non-escaped quote
"""val"ue\\\""" ->  value\\\"
```

The following regex *almost* works for me, except that it is also stripping backslashes when there is an even number of them before a quote, when I only want to escape double and single quote characters.

```
(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*[\"']
```

Comment: Why is `"""val"ue\\\"""` should result in `value\\\"`? What about `"` in-between `value`?

Comment: I was thinking about something like `(["'])(?:\\.|.)*?\1` to match entire quote (`\.` is used to match *any escaped character*) but above example makes it harder.

Comment: Hello, please see both marked questions. They will definitely help you to port. Otherwise edit your question to reflect differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you match those backslashes and they are removed. To keep them, *capture* these backslashes, and replace with `$1` placeholder:

```
s.replaceAll("((?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*)[\"']", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ksZTHW/1).

The `((?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*)` is now wrapped in `(...)` and you may refer to the value captured within this group by using `$1` in the replacement pattern.

Comment: This worked nicely for me. Thanks!